# How to auto-visualize the preview of a html file in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to create a html file which displays some images like the following

```
file = localFile.create('test.html')
file.writeString(str(html))
```

Is there any way the intellij pops up a new tab (after the string is written to the file) which shows the preview of this newly updated html file?

Or if this is not possible, it is okay to pop up a new tab of the html file so I can manually click the 'preview in intellij' option.

Comment: No easy way. It is possible to create a plugin that will trigger the action based on the editor's content though.

Comment: I think the following logic should be enough for my current case:
`import webbrowser;
webbrowser.open(file.toString())`
which opens a new tab for the html file and we can use the intellij preview to check the file in intellij.